# What changes need to be made to the code in order to stop the output from containing duplicate object

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, runnable

The program sorts objects according to their names. The program utilizes multithreading, but when I use it the output contains a duplicate of the first item in the list. The program worked fine before multithreading (specifically Runnable) was added. The error occurs right after it sorts the list though.

This is part of the ClassRank class that contains sorting the method:

```
public List<Student> nameOrder(List<Student> students)
    {
        //Keeps sorting until sorted.
        boolean notSorted = true;       

        while (notSorted)
        {
            //Count keeps track of how many items are in order.
            int count = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++)
            {

                //nameFront is a name ahead of the nameBehind in the list.
                String nameFront = students.get(i).getName();
                String nameBehind = students.get(i + 1).getName();
                //Determines lexicographical relationship between the names.
                if (nameFront.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBehind) > 0 )
                {
                    Student studentFront = students.get(i);
                    students.set(i, students.get(i + 1));
                    students.set(i + 1, studentFront);
                }
                else if (nameFront.compareToIgnoreCase(nameBehind) == 0)
                {
                    double frontWorth = students.get(i).pointValue();
                    double behindWorth = students.get(i + 1).pointValue();
                    if(frontWorth < behindWorth)
                    {
                        Student studentFront = students.get(i);
                        students.set(i, students.get(i + 1));
                        students.set(i + 1, studentFront);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if (count ==  students.size())
            {
                notSorted = false;
            }           
        }   
        return students; 
    }
```

This is inside the main method:

```
List<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
//students is the list made from extracting the data file with
        //the objects
        for(Student student: students)
        {
            list1.add(student);
        }
ClassRank listNames = new ClassRank();
Thread name = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Command to sort students alphabetically
                listNames.nameOrder(list1);
            }
        });
        name.start();
        for (Student i : list1)
        {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
```

This is the output for sorted list

```
Matthew Diaz      3.6 1420 3
Carl Baab         1.6 750 2
Connor Morgan     3.2 1260 3
Daniel Deyoung    2.8 460 3
David Navas       2.9 1450 1
Dominic Mazza     3.9 1460 3
Ethan Gieger      3.5 1310 3
George Scaglione  3.5 1300 1
Hayle Short       3.8 1410 7
Jake Orlick       4.0 1340 5
Joshua Saunders   3.5 1510 7
Matthew Diaz      3.6 1420 3
Robert Dick       3.8 1460 2
Samuel Rodriguez  3.8 1360 3
```

Comment: This code might produce that result, throw a `ConcurentModificationException` or show the unsorted ArrayList.

Comment: ArrayList is not concurrently accessible, so you will get some interesting effects.
You need to wait for your thread's execution to finish before printing the results.

Comment: Try to add a `name.join()` after `name.start();`.

Comment: Why are you sleeping the thread in the sort?
It looks like an inefficient implementation of a bubble sort, not a mult-threaded sort.

Comment: It is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts The purpose of the program is to test processor speed in doing multiple sorts

Comment: @JohannesKuhn solved the issue, thank you!

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that might solve the issue, but it does make the thread somewhat redundant.